# How can I pass a value from my PHP to a javascript function?

Tags: html

```
    <p align="left">
        <b>Click this button to create div element dynamically:</b>

 <?php $qry = "SELECT COUNT(*)  AS count From Contact Where CustomerID=$pid";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$count = $row['count'];
echo  $count;
if($count >= 6)
{
?>
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="create div" onClick="popup();" />
<?php
}
else
{

  $num = 6 - $count ;   
  echo $num;
    ?>
<input id="btn1" type="button" value="create div" onClick="createDiv(<?php echo $num ?>);" />
<?php   
}


 ?>
```

I want to pass the "$num" to my create DIV function

if the $num is 6 it can create 6 div, if $num is 4 it can only generate up to 4 div only

this my createDiv function

```
var i=0;
    function createDiv(num)
    {


  if(i < num) {
        var divTag = document.createElement("div");

        divTag.id = "div1"+i;

        divTag.setAttribute("align","left");

        divTag.style.margin = "0px auto";

        divTag.className ="ex";

       divTag.innerHTML = "<img class='myimage' onclick='changeimage(this)' border='0' src='images/white_contact.png' width='60'/><table border='0'><tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type='text'></d></tr><tr><td>Title:</td><td><input type='text'></td></tr><tr><td>Contact:</td><td><input type='text'></td></tr></table>";

        document.getElementById("newdiv").appendChild(divTag)

      }

   i++;
   $( ".ex" ).draggable({containment:'parent',cursor:'pointer',opacity:0.6, });
 $( ".ex" ).droppable({ hoverClass:'border' });

    }
```

But now I can only create one DIV, why is this so?

Comment: using "i++" can increment i value, but you need a loop to execute several times the same code.

Answer (score 0):

You can cleanup your code a bit and use handlers for this kind of thing..

You seem to have jQuery installed (since you're using droppable and draggable)

HTML:

```
<input type='button' class='div-creator' data-div-id="<? echo $id ?>" value="Click Me">
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('body').on("click", '.div-creator', function() {
  var id = $(this).data("div-id");
  // And do whatever else you want to do here.
  // $(this) is the element that was clicked.  id is the div-id in the button tag.
});
```

Comment: I just want to get the number? int

Comment: I was answering the question in the title - but for your javascript - what do you get if you do console.log(typeof(num)) in your creatediv function?